# PHP: Removing text between first character and a (.)

Tags: php, explode

For example,

The variable `$creator` contains a username in the format `john.smith`.

How do I convert this into another variable for example `$creator1` which cuts down the username into the following format: `jsmith`.

So I want to remove everything between the first character and the '.' and put the result into another variable called `$creator1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$creator = 'john.smith';
list($name, $surname) = explode('.', $creator);

$creator1 = substr($name, 0, 1) . $surname;
```

Also possible is to treat string as an array of characters, so:

```
$creator1 = $name[0] . $surname;
```

**Edit:**

To check if `$creator` contains dot do:

```
$creator = 'john.smith';
if ( strpos($creator, '.') !== false ) { // contains dot
    list($name, $surname) = explode('.', $creator);
    $creator1 = substr($name, 0, 1) . $surname;
} else { // doesn't contain dot
    $creator1 = $creator;
}
```

Comment: i like the list as a result for an explode !

Comment: Tricky isn't it ? I got it from SO long time ago. ;-)

Comment: THANKS, i have just realized i only want to do this if the name actually contains a . as some dont, is there a way to use a if statement to only do this if the name contains a . otherwise ignore?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
$username = 'jhon.smith';
$new_string = $username{0} . substr($username, strpos($username,'.')+1, strlen($username));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it different ways, I explain you one:

```
$name = "jonh.smith";
$data = explode(".",$name); // This will separate the name using dot as delimiter
$name1 = $data[0]; // Has jonh
$name2 = $data[1]; // Has smith
$nick = substr($name1,0,1); // Gets the first char
$nick = $nick . $name2; // Appends smith
```

This is a fast-coded one, but you will get the idea.

Comment: Downvote for using PHP Short Codes - Removed due to your edit.

Comment: It's bad practice that isn't supported across all systems. Not good to suggest their use.

Comment: Ok, I see. The next time I'll add <?php instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fullname = 'john.smith';
$parts = explode('.', $fullname);
$lastname = $parts[1];  // smith
$firstname = $parts[0][0]; // j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$creator1 = substr($creator, 0, 1).substr($creator, strpos($creator, ".")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$creator = 'john.smith';
$parts = explode('.', $creator);
$condensed = $creator{0} . $parts[1];
print $condensed;
// jsmith
```

Comment: We concider `john.smith` insead of `John Smith`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
$creator = "john.smith";
$pos = strpos($creator,'.');
$creator1 = substr($creator,0,1).substr($creator,$pos+1,strlen($creator)-$pos);
echo $creator1; // jsmith
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$creator="john.smith"
$creator_split=explode('.',$creator);
$creator_first=str_split($creator_split[0]);
$creator1=$creator_first[0].$creator_split[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using my own variable please replace it with yours

```
$str = "john.smith";
$str1 = explode(".",$str);
$str2 = $str1[0];
$str3 = $str1[1];
$str4 = substr($str2,0,1);
$finalString = $str4.$str3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
$var1="john.smith";
$var2=preg_replace(array("/^(.{1})(.*)(\..*)/"),array("$1$3"),$var1);
echo $var2;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ROgj02

EDIT:
If a string doesn't content "." this expression just returns the same string:

```
$var1="john.smith";
$var2="johnsmith";
$res1=preg_replace(array("/^(.{1})(.*)(\..*)/"),array("$1$3"),$var1);
$res2=preg_replace(array("/^(.{1})(.*)(\..*)/"),array("$1$3"),$var2);
var_dump($res1,$res2);
```

it returns:

> string(7) "j.smith" string(9) "johnsmith"